# ffmpeg saturation fade-in start time not functioning?

Tags: ffmpeg

In the ffmpeg docs the hue filter gives examples of a saturation fade-in .This implies you can set the transition start time, but this is not working.

```
-vf hue="s=min(0\, max((t-START)/DURATION\, 1))"
```

There is a working example (as below) that allows a fade-in from 0secs, but not from your chosen start position.

```
-vf hue="s=min(t/DURATION\,1)"
```

Fade-out works just fine from a chosen start position, so I’m assuming it should work for fade-in. Is this an error in the example code, or am I missing something.

Thankyou

Edit..SOLVED:

```
hue="s=max(0\,min(1\,(t-START)/DURATION))"
```

Comment: Share full log of what you tried.

Comment: Edited as solved.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer (in the box below then click "Post Your Answer) instead of in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
hue="s=max(0\,min(1\,(t-START)/DURATION))"
```